# Is there an easy way to tell if a Logitech device uses a nano Receiver?

Tags: logitech-unifying-receiver

I want to sell Logitech USB nano receivers. I want to provide a list of supported devices.

On [aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256804415323342.html) they say you have to look at the S/N and see if it is between 13 and 19. But I have a K295 with S/N 22 here and the nano receiver works. So this technique cannot be used.

Another idea is to look into the quick start manual of the product. But some products are available as nano and also Unifying version. For example MK330 is available as [nano](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Logitech-Wireless-Keyboard-Battery-Compatible/dp/B009Z73SCG) and [Unifying](https://gzhls.at/blob/ldb/c/7/9/8/b78c55566a0364a78caecf6cfc1a777cdb29.pdf). So this technique cannot be used either.

So as I already told you the product name like MK330 is not reliable. But the M/N number can be used instead.

But how to say if a M/N uses nano or Unifying receivers?

Let's take a look at these M/Ns: Y-R0042 and Y-R0059. For Y-R0042 I know it uses nano receivers because I have one here. And Y-R0059 uses Unifying as [this](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/yMQAAOSw33Ff619T/s-l1600.jpg) image proofs.

Because nano and Unifying are different standards I hoped the FCC test report could tell about the used receiver.

[Y-R0042 FCC test report](https://fccid.io/JNZYR0042/Test-Report/Test-Report-pdf-2121385.pdf), [Y-R0059 FCC test report](https://fccid.io/JNZYR0059/Test-Report/Test-Report-pdf-2722316.pdf)

But it is strange because all values (frequency, channel number, modulation type...) are the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it worth the effort? eBay have them listed at £6 brand new. Presumably anyone looking for a 2nd hand one would know what they were in need of replacing.

Comment: People loose the receivers so they do not know which one to buy. There are even keyboards using Unifying while not wearing the Unifying logo.

Comment: … but something you're not going to get more than a fiver for… what's the point? Caveat emptor. Let *them* do the research. If you were being paid by the hour, you'd have already overspent.

Comment: The easy way would be to contact Logitech as a reseller and ask them.

Comment: @Mokubai I talked to the support but his English wasn't good so he didn't understand. I'll try to call them tomorrow.

Comment: Y-R0042 operates at entirely differently frequencies and Db strength than Y-R0059

Comment: @Ramhound Both operate at 2405MHz ~ 2474MHz. The stength I don't know. Could you please explain?